# ucwords(strtolower()) not working together php

Tags: php

I have code where I am extracting a name from a database, trying to reorder the word, and then changing it from all uppercase to word case. Everything I find online suggests my code should work, but it does not... Here is my code and the output:

```
$subjectnameraw = "SMITH, JOHN LEE";
$subjectlname = substr($subjectnameraw, 0, strpos($subjectnameraw, ",")); // Get the last name 
$subjectfname = substr($subjectnameraw, strpos($subjectnameraw, ",") + 1) . " "; // Get first name and middle name
$subjectname = ucwords(strtolower($subjectfname . $subjectlname)); // Reorder the name and make it lower case / upper word case
```

However, the output looks like this:

John Lee smith

The last name is ALWAYS lowercase no matter what I do. How can I get the last name to be uppercase as well?

Comment: Are you sure you checked ? See https://onecompiler.com/php/3ymf8k6q7

Comment: Yes, I’m sure. I copied and pasted what I had and have tested it a dozen different ways but it never changes. I didn’t think to test I. Onecompiler… if it’s not an error in the code idk what’s causing it to do that

Comment: @Cody_T Are you sure, that the added space in `$subjectfname = substr($subjectnameraw, strpos($subjectnameraw, ",") + 1) . " "` really is a space, not a tab or a non breaking space?

Comment: Yes. I have also tried adding the space in the last line, having a `.“ ”.` In between the names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code gives wrong results when there are multibyte characters in the names like RENÉ. The following solution uses the multibyte function `mb_convert_case`.

```
$subjectnameraw = "SMITH, JOHN LEE RENÉ";
list($lastName,$firstnName) = explode(', ',mb_convert_case($subjectnameraw,MB_CASE_TITLE,'UTF-8'));
echo $firstnName." ".$lastName;
```

Demo : https://3v4l.org/ekTQA

Comment: This worked. None of the names have any fancy characters like that, but for some reason this fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: In German, this also applies to all umlauts in names such as Björn, Sören or Jörg.